# GeoServer v2.18.0 Upgrade Web UI version of JQuery

Tags: geoserver, jquery

I am looking into how I would update the version of JQuery used in the Web UI part of GeoServer (v2.18.0). The current version (JQuery v1.12.4) has 4 medium vulnerabilities, so I am looking to replace that with v3.5.1

Any GeoServer Developers around? I am a developer myself, but I have very little experience with GeoServer.

Update: This isn't off-topic, it is a library that GeoServer include and it needs updating. It isn't directly affecting GeoServer, but JQuery is backwards compatible. So there must be a way to update it?

Comment: **Responsible Disclosure of Security Issues**
If you encounter a security vulnerability in GeoServer please take care to report in a responsible fashion:
Keep exploit details out of mailing list and issue tracker (send details to geoserver-security@lists.osgeo.org)
Please send a mail directly to geoserver-security@lists.osgeo.org (moderated list with no possibility to subscribe, please just send directly to the address, the mail will be evaluated and eventually posted) and provide information about the security issue you might have found there.